# docker-compose.yml, postgress, how to setup db, tables and prepop in an init.sql file?

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose

I would like to add a DB, table and prepopulate with some kind of init.sql file.  not sure what the init.sql file looks like.  Also not sure where I would be putting the ADD command.

This docker-compose.yml file works

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  postgre:
    image: postgres:11.1-alpine
    ports:
      - "5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: 'user'
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'password'
      POSTGRESS_DB: 'db_amex01'
    volumes:
      - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `*.sh` script(s) and/or `*.sql` instructions to the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` directory (basically how you have in your `docker-compose.yml` file already).

An example of a shell script to create a user:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "$POSTGRES_DB" <<-EOSQL
    CREATE USER docker;
    CREATE DATABASE docker;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE docker TO docker;
EOSQL
```

You can generate your `.sql` file from an existing database by "dumping" the data with `psql -U <username> -d <dbname> -1 -f <filename>.sql`. You can then add the `.sql` file to your `./init/` directory.

This is documented at https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/postgres#how-to-extend-this-image.

Comment: what would the host be?  I am still having issues with connection.  even to loal host.

Comment: localhost (or the ip address of the docker bridge interface)